# How normal distribution and normal approximation are related?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The formula for normal distribution.

$f(x) = \frac{e^\frac{-(x-u)^2}{2q^2}}{q\sqrt{2*\pi}}$

where $u$ is the expected value, $q$ is the standard deviation.

Normal approximation defines $u=n*p$ and $q^2 = n*p*(1-p)$

Please consider coin flipping example. For this $p=1/2$, $u=n/2$, $q^2=n*1/2*(1-1/2)=n/4$

Putting $u$ and $q$ to the formula of normal distribution we should have $f(x) = \frac{e^\frac{-2(x-n/2)^2}{n}}{\sqrt{\pi*n/2}}$

I want to double check my understanding because in R. Sedgewick's "Algorithms in C 3rd edition" on page 86 given resulted formula as $f(x) =  \frac{e^\frac{-(x-n/2)^2}{n}}{\sqrt{\pi*n/2}}$ (i.e. it missed 2 in the nominator of power of $e$).

Comment: $e^{-(x-n/2)^2/n}$ is definitely wrong for fair coin flips, since that implies twice the variance is $n$, but twice the variance is definitely $n/2$. One possible way this error could come about is if there was a Poisson approximation in the middle, but the Poisson approximation is not suitable for fair coin flips anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer looks good to me. The factor in the exponent is $1/(2q^2)$, whilst that in the denominator, *under the square-root*, is $2 q^2$---one is the reciprocal of the other. This is the case in the answer you give: your exponent-factor is $2$ and your denominator-factor is $1/2$. The answer you cite in the book(?) does not satisfy this: one is $1$ and the other $1/2$.

This doesn't mean that your answer is necessarily right---although, it is! Rather, I am explaining how the book's answer is necessarily wrong.

It is always a good idea to have little sanity checks like this in mind. They are good ways for spotting mistakes and can save a lot of hassle! I emphasise, though, that they do not guarantee correctness: if you replace your $2$s with $15$s, then the sanity check still holds; but the answer would be wrong.